# buildroot does not regard config changes

Tags: compilation, buildroot

Im playing around with buildroot together with linaro 2016.11 for arm. 
Im actually building the latest Linux Kernel for the i.MX6 Processors. 
So far so good.

I have setup the buildroot config with

```
$ make makeconfig
```

I have configured an external toolchain (the linaro one). I also configured the uboot to be built. In the uboot section, i had to choose the appropriate board name for the defconfig.

Now the problem:

I have done a full make which was successfull without any errors. 
After that, i have changed the uboot board name to something which does not exist in the source. Just to make sure everything is working correct.

i have restartet the build process with

```
$ make uboot-rebuild
```

to my confusion, the build was sucessfull. After a deeper look to the shell commands, i saw, that the new config was just ignored. I have tried everything without success. It only rebuilds correctly after i do a

```
$make clean
$make
```

but this will build the whole thing again and it takes a lot of time.

I hope someone could help me with that and give me some hint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make <pkg>-rebuild` rebuilds the package without applying a new configuration, so what happens is correct.

After changing the U-Boot configuration you have to run `make uboot-reconfigure`. This command first applies the configuration, then it does the same actions as `uboot-rebuild`.

See also the Buildroot manual, section [Understanding how to rebuild packages](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#rebuild-pkg).